# Swipe ViewPager still lag inner NonSwipeableViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager NonSwipeable(cannot swipe) with 2 fragment. In second fragment, I set normal ViewPager(can swipe) with Tab Indicator. But when I swipe that ViewPager  , its look lag.

Parent Activity

```
public NonSwipeableViewPager mPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);y;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

....

mAdapter = new FragmentSearchAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), SearchActivity.this);
        mAdapter.addFragment("search histori");
        mAdapter.addFragment("search result");

        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

....

}
```

this is Custom ViewPager NonSwipeable :

```
 public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

        public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Second Fragment

```
 @Bind(R.id.pager)
    public ViewPager mPager;
    @Bind(R.id.tabs)
    PagerSlidingTabStrip mPagerSlidingTabStrip;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result2, container, false);

        mAdapter = new FragmentSearchResultAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity());
        mAdapter.addFragment("Business");
        mAdapter.addFragment("Product");
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mPager);
        return rootView;

    }
```

so how to solve it ? sorry for my english

Comment: How are yo loading your ViewPager? and your content?

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo Please Check my edit question.. thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is :

```
 mAdapter = new FragmentSearchResultAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity());
```

I Change with :

```
mAdapter = new FragmentSearchResultAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity());
```